# chromeWebSecurity is not working in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I've tried to test login by google.
And get an error "Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load".
This is m test code.
Before getting `input[name="identifier"]` element I see this error.

Code of my test:

```
cy.visit(`https://app.develop.weeek.net/sign-in`);

cy.get('.socials__social')
  .eq(0)
  .click();

cy.get('input[name="identifier"]')
  .type(Cypress.env.TEST_GOOGE_EMAIL)
  .should('have.value', Cypress.env.TEST_GOOGE_EMAIL);
```

I've tried all the ways to turn off checking CORS-requests for Chrome.
But no one is working.
I open cypress by `cypress open --config chromeWebSecurity=false` command.

My `cypress.json`:

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "viewportWidth": 1280,
  "viewportHeight": 768
}
```

Why `chromeWebSecurity` is not working?
How to turn off the CORS checking?

Comment: Any update on this